# Two different solutions for the irrational inequality $(x-1) \sqrt{x^2-x-2} \geq 0$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, contest-math

Upon solving this problem with the concept that I have understood about solving inequalities until now, I got the following range for $x$ :-
$(x-1) \sqrt{x^2-x-2} \geq 0$
$\Rightarrow(x-1) \sqrt{(x-2)(x+1)} \geq 0$
$\Rightarrow(x-1)^2 (x-2)(x+1)\geq 0 \text{ ; upon squaring both sides }$
$\Rightarrow x\in(-\infty,-1]\cup[2,\infty)$

This is the solution range that I got for the given inequality and I have confirmed this solution by checking this in Wolfram Alpha. But this solution only comes up if I give the modified problem statement as $(x-1)^2 (x-2)(x+1)\geq 0$ i.e. after squaring both sides, on the website as you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%29%5E2%20%28x-2%29%28x%2B1%29%5Cgeq%200).

And I thought that this should be the correct answer but when I give the original problem statement into the website, it gives the result as $x\in[2,\infty)$ as you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%29%20%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2-x-2%7D%20%5Cgeq%200).

Now I am confused as to which one is the correct solution for this problem. Why there are two different solutions to the same problem? How a simple act of squaring both sides is changing the solutions completely? Please help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: you cannot simply square both sides. $(x-1)^2\ge 0$ does not imply that $x-1\ge 0$

Comment: But even when I checked that problem statement in Wolfram Alpha it is also showing the same answer as I got. Does that mean Wolfram Alpha is giving a wrong solution?

Comment: Ok...Can someone please put down the way to solve this problem then with pen and paper? That will be really helpful.

Comment: $x\ge0$ is not equivalent to $\sqrt{x}\ge0$ as $\sqrt{x}$ might be negative too. Also in wolframalpha you inputted your third expression and not the originial question giving you the wrong answer

Comment: You should see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%29%5Csqrt%28%28x-2%29%28x%2B1%29%29%5Cgeq+0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a full solution: $(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-x-2}\ge 0$ automatically means that $x-1\ge 0$ (since a square root must be non-negative) or $x^2-x-2=0$ (the inequality is also valid when the square root is zero). In this case we get $x\ge 1$, or $x=-1$. However we also need $x^2-x-2\ge 0$ such that we are not taking the square root of a negative number. In this case we have $$x^2-x-2\ge 0\longrightarrow (x-2)(x+1)\ge 0\longrightarrow x\le -1\text{ or }x\ge 2$$
Combining these constraints with $x\ge 1$ or $x=-1$, we get $x=-1\text{ or }x\in [2, \infty)$.

Comment: This is helpful. I should be careful in squaring the inequalities from the next time.

Comment: You missed the solution $x=-1$, sqrt can be zero, not just positive.

Comment: @Macavity right. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

$x\ge0$ is obviously not the same as $x^2\ge0$ !

For this problem, as a square root is positive by definition, the inequality reduces to

$$x-1\ge0,$$  provided that the argument of the square root is non-negative.

Comment: Then how come the website is also giving the same solution as I got. I thought we can trust Wolfram Alpha as it is a credible source.

Comment: @Ganit it gave you that solution only after you put in your invalid "modified" inequality.

Comment: Even with your reduced problem statement to $x-1 \geq 0$, we get the solution range to be $x \geq 1$ which is not the correct answer.

Comment: "$x\ge0$ is obviously not the same as $x^2\ge0$" Can you give some example to prove your this statement

Comment: @Ganit see my answer

Comment: @Ganit please check out my solution

Comment: $x\ge0$ is obviously not the same as $x^2\ge0$ ! : yes, I am also confused here. I mean let's say $5 \geq 0$ then it also means that $5^2 \geq 0$. Same question as @JitendraSingh.

Comment: @Ganit $(-5)^2\ge 0$ does't mean that $-5\ge 0$

Comment: The argument in the sqrt can be zero, hence $x=-1$ works too.

Comment: @JitendraSingh: $x^2\ge0$ is a tautology. $x\ge0$ is not.

Comment: @JitendraSingh $$(a\implies b) \not\equiv (a\iff b)$$

Answer (score 0):

In your $2$nd step to the $3$rd step, you just squared a term without realizing that the negative values are extraneous and don't actually work.

Also, when you input the inequality into Wolfram Alpha, you input the incorrect inequality; your $3$rd step; not the original equation. This is why Wolfram Alpha got it "wrong".

Hope this helps!